# How to get Integrate to resolve integrals term by term?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Integrate seems to return a whole expression unresolved whenever just a single term is unintegrable. How do I get it to return the integral of all terms that are resolvable with the only the unintegrable terms unresolved?

For example, I think Integrate[x^2 + (Log[x]Log[1-x])^2,x] should return
x^3/3 + Integrate[(Log[x]Log[1-x])^2,x]; instead it returns the whole expression unintegrated.  Even invoking Simplify or FullSimplify doesn't help.

I'm Integrating an expression that, when expanded, has only one unintegrable term, but I would like to have the results for the other terms.

Comment: Map[Integrate[#, x] &, x^2 + (Log[x] Log[1 - x])^2]

Answer (score 1):

[`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) onto the expression. "`Map[f,expr]` or `f/@expr` applies `f` to each element on the first level in `expr`."

```
Integrate[#, x] & /@ (x^2 + (Log[x] Log[1 - x])^2)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the pointer to the Map function. I'm just getting back to using Mathematica after about a 15 year hiatus, so have to lot to catch up on.

Comment: But the question remains: Why aren't the linear properties of the Integral operator incorporated into the function itself?  Is their some subtle advantage or some subtle problem avoided by not using this property?